# Error using self created tableviewcell

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to design a `UITableView` and a customized `UITableViewCell` class, however, whenever I use my own `UITableViewCell` class, the app crashes with the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It works fine with the default class `UITableViewCell` though.

Here is the code in my class:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!   
}
```

Comment: Please put more information about where the error is originated exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you correctly implement the UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate?
Especially, in the cellForRawAtIndexPath function you should have something like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as TableViewCell
```

"Cell" refers to the identifier of the custom cell. You can set it up in the storyboard -> Show the Attributes Inspector -> Identifier

[image: change cell identifier]